# defining clean task on rootProject overrides default clean task in java subprojects

Tags: java, groovy, gradle

I have a multi-project gradle build. In my root build.gradle i have defined the clean task:

```
// build.gradle
task clean
```

and i have many subprojects that apply the java plugin:

```
// module1/build.gradle
apply plugin: 'java'
```

I have noticed that the default clean behaviour is overriden by the declaration of the task in the root project.

```
// build.gradle
task cleanMyTask1
task cleanMyTask2
clean.dependsOn cleanMyTask1, cleanMyTask2
```

and on the commandLine

```
// command line
gradlew clean 
// oh no, the java plugin clean tasks have disappeared!
```

I have various extensions to the clean task that need to be defined before the subprojects are compiled, so i needed to define the clean task before hand. Is there a way around this problem or am i structuring my build in a bad way?

Comment: There may be some misunderstanding here. I don't see how your clean task declaration would have any effect on (execution of) clean tasks in other projects.

Comment: If i run the clean task on the root project, all the clean tasks of the subprojects created by the java plugin no longer execute, Do you mean to say i must now individually call these from each individual subproject instead? I liked the way I could call all the `clean` tasks on every subproject at once.

Comment: Something must be wrong with your build then, or you are misinterpreting the results. Task declarations in one project don't have any effect on tasks declared in other projects, and `gradlew clean` will always execute all existing `clean` tasks "below" the current working directory.

Comment: Hmmm. Ok then, I'll have to have another look at my code :)